# Port 3031 is being opened by launchd

Tags: macos, launchd

I want to use the port 3031 for our application but it is in use by something with PID 1. It is being opened with launchd and I just reset my laptop so it must be an apple process.

[image]

Comment: What is the actual question you wish to ask? All so far is just a statement of what you have found. For example you could ask how to find out what 3031 is being used for, or how to find a reliably free port, or how to make service discovery a dynamic process using Zeroconf or similar.

Answer (score 1):

> | Port | TCP or UDP | Service or protocol name | RFC | Service name | Used by |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 3031 | TCP/UDP | Remote AppleEvents | — | eppc | Program Linking, Remote Apple Events |

[TCP and UDP ports used by Apple software products - Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT202944)

For more info on Apple events

- Wikipedia has an overview of an [Apple event](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_event)
- The [Apple Events Programming Guide](https://applescriptlibrary.files.wordpress.com/2013/11/apple-events-programming-guide.pdf) explains everything there is to know about Apple events, and page 63 begins a section on sending remote Apple events
- You can enable or disable remote Apple events from Sharing settings: [Allow remote Apple events on Mac - macOS User Guide](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mchlp1398/mac)